# Tools to predict next big tech

Tags: programming-languages

What tools/sources can be used to predict the next big languages and toolsets?

**As an example**, if I wanted to compare the prospective future of Node.js+Express.js against Ruby+Rails, where could I look?

So far, these sources come to mind:

- [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/)
- [Git repos by language](https://github.com/languages)
- Opinions on Quora, StackOverflow, etc.

Comment: How about the growth in questions asked on StackOverflow month over month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sponsorship and/or adoption by a company. Building out tools and infrastructure for a new language (rather than a new framework) is hard, costly and time consuming.

Google put tonnes of effort into making Eclipse better for J2SE. Ditto Apple for Objective-C. Microsoft doesn't just release languages, it releases entirely new development environments. If you're serious about your toolchains, pick a language with serious corporate backing :)